# How to limit the number of database connections that SOLR makes when indexing?

Tags: mysql, database, solr, lucene

You can increase the number of the database connections allowed for the DB, but that's not really a solution. If SOLR makes lots of connections when indexing, some other parts of your site can start getting "Too many connections", which is not good.

Actually SOLR full import makes so many connections that it fails for me with 150 max connections.

Here are some stats:
1) I initiate full reindexing
2) Few seconds after that:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

| Id  | User       | Host            | db         | Command | Time |
| 158 | xxx | localhost:58804 | yyy | Query   |    0 |
| 159 | xxx | localhost:58810 | yyy | Sleep   |    3 |
| 160 | xxx | localhost:58811 | yyy | Sleep   |    1 |
| 161 | xxx | localhost:58812 | yyy | Sleep   |    1 |
...
| 255 | xxx | localhost:58906 | yyy | Sleep   |    0 |
| 256 | xxx | localhost:58907 | yyy | Sleep   |    0 |
```

3) Import fails because of:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

I didn't find a parameter to place in solrconfig.xml to solve this. SOLR version is 1.3 by the way.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. Just a bit more info: in the logs I see:

```
INFO: Creating a connection for entity abc with URL: jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2/xyz
INFO: Time taken for getConnection(): 9
```

and this gets repeated for hundreds of times, until it hits my local max connections limit(151) and errors out. I have no idea why SOLR is opening a new connection for every entity. I hope this is fixable, because it doesn't look like a correct behavior. Does anyone know if upgrading to 1.4 or 4.0 can fix this?

Thanks again!

P.P.S. I will also add a guess. It opens exactly one connection per entity or maybe sub-entity: the structure that I have is one giant entity and over 160 child entities.
And http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201205.mbox/%3CA1EB2532250E8945BC3E1FA3AE836F6BE1118F18@adonia.local.uship.com%3E says that solr has a bug... If someone knows a fix other then upgrading, please tell.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Two years later we are having the same issue!

Comment: No :( I'm no longer working for the company where I had this issue ...